# Visibility of the Variables in the Methods

Tags: java, variables, debugging, methods

I am working on a students management program which lists the names(VN), surnames(NN) and degrees(Noten) of the students / a specified student after entering his name

In this code there is a java method which is not able to access the declared arrays:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Aufgabe1_Sulyman {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String NN[] = new String[30];
    String VN[] = new String[30];
    int Noten[] = new int[30];
    int anzahl;
    int option;
    int index;

    do {
        System.out.println("Die zur Verfügung gestellten Optionen: ");
        System.out.println("1) Eingabe Daten aller Schüler");
        System.out.println("2)Ausgabe Daten aller Schüler");
        System.out.println("3) Eingabe Daten eines Schülers");
        System.out.println("4) Ausgabe Daten eines Schülers");
        System.out.println("5) Notendurchschnittsberechnung");
        System.out.println("6) Suche nach Nachnamen eines Schülers");
        System.out.println("7) Beenden");
        option = sc.nextInt();
        switch(option) {
            case 1:
                eingabeAlle(VN, NN, Noten); 
            break;
            case 2:
                ausgabeAlle(VN, NN, Noten);
            break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("Die Nummer des Schülers");
                index = sc.nextInt();
                eingabe(NN, VN, Noten, index);
            break; 
            case 4:
                ausgabe(VN, NN, Noten);
            break; 
            case 5:
                System.out.println("die Anzahl der Schüler: ");
                anzahl = sc.nextInt();
                durchschnitt(anzahl, Noten);
            break; 
            case 6:
                suche(NN);
            break; 
        }

    } while(option != 7);


}

    // Die Methoden
    public static void eingabeAlle(String[] VN, String[] NN, int[] Noten) {
        for (int i = 0; i < VN.length; i++) {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Geben Sie Den Vornamen des Schülers ein: ");
            VN[i] = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Geben Sie den Nachnamen des Schülers ein: ");
            NN[i] = sc.nextLine(); 
            System.out.println("Geben Sie die Note des Schülers ein:");
            Noten[i] = sc.nextInt();
            // anzahl =+ VN;
            // int sum =+ VN[i];
         } 
    }
    public static void eingabe(String[] VN, String[] NN, int[] Noten, int i) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Geben Sie die Daten der Schüler ein:");
        System.out.println("Die notwendigen Daten sind: " + "\n" + "Nachnamen");
        NN[i] = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Vornamen");
        VN[i] = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Noten");
        Noten[i] = sc.nextInt();

    }
    public static void ausgabeAlle(String[] VN, String[] NN, int[] Noten) {
        for (int i = 0; i < NN.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Die Note für den Schüler: " + NN[i]+ " " + VN[i] + "ist: " + Noten[i]);
    }
        }
    public static void ausgabe(String VN, String NN, int Noten) {
        System.out.println("Der Schüler" + NN + " "+ VN + " hat die Note" + Noten);

    }
    public static void durchschnitt(int anzahl,int[] Noten) {
        float d = 0.0F;
        for (int i = 0; i < Noten.length; i++) {
        d += Noten[i];
    }
    System.out.println("Der Durchschnitt der Noten aller Schüler ist: " + (d/anzahl));
    }

    public static void suche(String[] NN) {
        System.out.println("Der Nachname des Schülers: ");
        String name = sc.nextLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < NN.length; i++) {
            if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(NN[i])) {
                System.out.println(name+ " ist vorhanden");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The problem i face are in the code line 37 and 84. My tutor pointed out that it has to do with the:

> **Visibility of the Variables in the Methods**

If having any questions, let me know. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why are your parameters named NN and VN? Use descriptive names! Code is meant to be readable. Also in Java parameters and variables start with lowercase.

Comment: So the parameters need to to be lowercase, although the arrays(in this case) are declared uppercase in my code? @m0skit0

Comment: All should be declared lowercase. It's a naming convention. If someone else gave you the previous declarations I wouldn't trust his Java knowledge too much :p

Comment: Makes sense, they are from me

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-naming-conventions/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good you are learning Java

Please add new Scanner object in your method @ line 87 and method ausgabe parameters should be changed

```
 public static void ausgabe(String[] vN, String[] nN, int[] noten) {
        System.out.println("Der Schüler" + nN + " " + vN + " hat die Note" + noten);
    }
```

[image]

Full Code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Aufgabe1_Sulyman {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String NN[] = new String[30];
        String VN[] = new String[30];
        int Noten[] = new int[30];
        int anzahl;
        int option;
        int index;

        do {
            System.out.println("Die zur Verfügung gestellten Optionen: ");
            System.out.println("1) Eingabe Daten aller Schüler");
            System.out.println("2)Ausgabe Daten aller Schüler");
            System.out.println("3) Eingabe Daten eines Schülers");
            System.out.println("4) Ausgabe Daten eines Schülers");
            System.out.println("5) Notendurchschnittsberechnung");
            System.out.println("6) Suche nach Nachnamen eines Schülers");
            System.out.println("7) Beenden");
            option = sc.nextInt();
            switch (option) {
            case 1:
                eingabeAlle(VN, NN, Noten);
                break;
            case 2:
                ausgabeAlle(VN, NN, Noten);
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("Die Nummer des Schülers");
                index = sc.nextInt();
                eingabe(NN, VN, Noten, index);
                break;
            case 4:
                ausgabe(VN, NN, Noten);
                break;
            case 5:
                System.out.println("die Anzahl der Schüler: ");
                anzahl = sc.nextInt();
                durchschnitt(anzahl, Noten);
                break;
            case 6:
                suche(NN);
                break;
            }

        } while (option != 7);

    }

    // Die Methoden
    public static void eingabeAlle(String[] VN, String[] NN, int[] Noten) {
        for (int i = 0; i < VN.length; i++) {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Geben Sie Den Vornamen des Schülers ein: ");
            VN[i] = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Geben Sie den Nachnamen des Schülers ein: ");
            NN[i] = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Geben Sie die Note des Schülers ein:");
            Noten[i] = sc.nextInt();
            // anzahl =+ VN;
            // int sum =+ VN[i];
        }
    }

    public static void eingabe(String[] VN, String[] NN, int[] Noten, int i) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Geben Sie die Daten der Schüler ein:");
        System.out.println("Die notwendigen Daten sind: " + "\n" + "Nachnamen");
        NN[i] = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Vornamen");
        VN[i] = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Noten");
        Noten[i] = sc.nextInt();

    }

    public static void ausgabeAlle(String[] VN, String[] NN, int[] Noten) {
        for (int i = 0; i < NN.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Die Note für den Schüler: " + NN[i] + " " + VN[i] + "ist: " + Noten[i]);
        }
    }

    public static void ausgabe(String[] vN, String[] nN, int[] noten) {
        System.out.println("Der Schüler" + nN + " " + vN + " hat die Note" + noten);

    }

    public static void durchschnitt(int anzahl, int[] Noten) {
        float d = 0.0F;
        for (int i = 0; i < Noten.length; i++) {
            d += Noten[i];
        }
        System.out.println("Der Durchschnitt der Noten aller Schüler ist: " + (d / anzahl));
    }

    public static void suche(String[] NN) {
        System.out.println("Der Nachname des Schülers: ");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name = sc.nextLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < NN.length; i++) {
            if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(NN[i])) {
                System.out.println(name + " ist vorhanden");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: And more of bugs, Thanks @Sri

Comment: I have added full code can you please us that @Jwan

Comment: It is working perfectly, are you able to explain about your code, like the parameters of the method ausgabe(), why do they look like this ausgabe(vN, nN) and not -> ausgabe(VN, NN). Are those the so called instances?

Comment: Super, Can you please vote me OR accept the answer . Regarding Code the ausgabe method has mismatch in parameter type in Switch case you are sending the array Noten ausgabe(VN, NN, Noten);

Comment: I did, it is recorded but not displayed publicly because of the few votes number of mine.

Comment: Thanks happy coding :) @Jwan

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StudentManagement {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int maxStudents = 30;
        String[] surnames = new String[maxStudents];
        String[] names = new String[maxStudents];
        int[] grades = new int[maxStudents];
        int count = 0;

        do {
            System.out.println("Die zur Verfügung gestellten Optionen: ");
            System.out.println("1) Eingabe Daten aller Schüler");
            System.out.println("2) Ausgabe Daten aller Schüler");
            System.out.println("3) Eingabe Daten eines Schülers");
            System.out.println("4) Ausgabe Daten eines Schülers");
            System.out.println("5) Notendurchschnittsberechnung");
            System.out.println("6) Suche nach Nachnamen eines Schülers");
            System.out.println("7) Beenden");
            int option = sc.nextInt();

            switch (option) {
                case 1:
                    count = inputAll(surnames, names, grades, maxStudents);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    outputAll(surnames, names, grades, count);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    int index = sc.nextInt();
                    if (index >= 0 && index < count) {
                        input(surnames, names, grades, index);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Ungültige Indexnummer.");
                    }
                    break;
                case 4:
                    index = sc.nextInt();
                    if (index >= 0 && index < count) {
                        output(surnames[index], names[index], grades[index]);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Ungültige Indexnummer.");
                    }
                    break;
                case 5:
                    calculateAverage(grades, count);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    search(surnames, count);
                    break;
                case 7:
                    System.exit(0);
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Ungültige Option. Bitte erneut versuchen.");
            }
        } while (true);
    }

    public static int inputAll(String[] surnames, String[] names, int[] grades, int maxStudents) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < maxStudents; i++) {
            System.out.println("Geben Sie den Nachnamen des Schülers ein (oder 'exit' zum Beenden): ");
            String surname = sc.nextLine();

            if (surname.equals("exit")) {
                break;
            }

            System.out.println("Geben Sie den Vornamen des Schülers ein: ");
            String name = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Geben Sie die Note des Schülers ein:");
            int grade = sc.nextInt();

            surnames[count] = surname;
            names[count] = name;
            grades[count] = grade;
            count++;
            sc.nextLine(); // Consume newline character
        }

        return count;
    }

    public static void input(String[] surnames, String[] names, int[] grades, int index) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Geben Sie den Nachnamen des Schülers ein: ");
        surnames[index] = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Geben Sie den Vornamen des Schülers ein: ");
        names[index] = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Geben Sie die Note des Schülers ein: ");
        grades[index] = sc.nextInt();
    }

    public static void outputAll(String[] surnames, String[] names, int[] grades, int count) {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            output(surnames[i], names[i], grades[i]);
        }
    }

    public static void output(String surname, String name, int grade) {
        System.out.println("Der Schüler " + surname + " " + name + " hat die Note " + grade);
    }

    public static void calculateAverage(int[] grades, int count) {
        if (count == 0) {
            System.out.println("Keine Schülerdaten vorhanden.");
            return;
        }

        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            sum += grades[i];
        }

        double average = (double) sum / count;
        System.out.println("Der Durchschnitt der Noten aller Schüler ist: " + average);
    }

    public static void search(String[] surnames, int count) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Geben Sie den Nachnamen des Schülers ein, den Sie suchen: ");
        String searchName = sc.nextLine();

        boolean found = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            if (surnames[i].equalsIgnoreCase(searchName)) {
                output(surnames[i], names[i], grades[i]);
                found = true;
            }
        }

        if (!found) {
            System.out.println(searchName + " wurde nicht gefunden.");
        }
    }
}
```